# Apache HttpClient 4.5: Connection Resets

Tags: java, https, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using httpClient version 4.5 to connect with our external vendor site. We do not need any connection pool or persistent connection, so I am using the BasicHttpClientConnectionManager to create the HttpClient.

This works fine for minimal number of requests, but if I test this for 1TPS for 1 hour, by the end of the test, we start seeing intermittent connection resets. (guessing request count > 100)

I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://apiURL:443: Connection reset

Please find below the code snippet for making connection.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), new X509TrustManager[] { new DefaultTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslsf).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();

HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(1, false);

RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(Integer.parseInt(30000)).setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(30000)).setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000).setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).setRetryHandler(retryHandler).evictExpiredConnections().build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(<endpoint>);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(requestData));
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I saw that fix for a similar issue reported is already available with version 4.5. (Ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1655) provided by [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg)

If thats the case, not sure why I am still facing this issue. Could someone please help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of the opposite endpoint resetting the connection?

Comment: Thanks for the response, [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) . From the trace we ran with the Network team here, it is seen that the Source, which is our server has been sending a lot of resets (RST) when the Destination host requests an ACK from us. So, thats the reason I am trying to figure out if it is an issue with the HttpClient we use.

Comment: At this point, what we have done is to increase the number of retries to 3 (using DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler), as we noticed that some of the requests that were hit by connection reset error gets processed successfully after the retry. But, this doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution for the issue we are facing.

Comment: I _suspect_ the server just cannot keep up with the load and drops connections it is unable to serve. For safe and idempotent methods a retry strategy should be a perfectly adequate solution.

Comment: Thanks [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg), I guess you are right, we had also come up with a similar conclusion. Please do let me know if there is anything else that I can try out from the connection stand point with the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg),

I had been using the httpclient version 4.5.3 when I was still seeing the connection reset errors as posted above.

Later noticed that the fix for reset issue was committed to the version 4.5.1 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1655). So, just tried updating that particular version, ran a test and not seeing the connection reset errors any more.
I had expected that this fix should also be available in the higher versions starting from 4.5.1. But, I guess its somehow missed out in the higher versions, have verified that its still an issue with version 4.5.3 for sure.

So, conclusion is that the connection reset error was fixed using httpclient 4.5.1 jar.

Thanks!

Comment: I fund it a bit difficult to believe but so be it.

Comment: Yea, I was also not thinking about this possibility. And, I wouldn't have been so sure, if I had not tried running multiple rounds of test using different versions. This was just a trial, but I am happy that fixed it. Hope you would be adding the fix to higher versions as well.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what to fix given that HTTPCLIENT-1655 is present in all 4.5.x versions since 4.5.1. I did double-check.