# Getting Connection reset exception first time while calling API after sometime of interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, connection-pooling

We are making a post call to an API, when we start calling this API after some time interval(most of the time in our case 10 mins, rarely we get if interval is 5 mins) we get Connection reset exception for the first attempt, then rest of the immediate calls works fine, but if there is interval of 10 minutes in calling this API and then call again, we get such exceptions in first call after that interval.
We are using Java spring-boot Resttamplate to make API calls and using Apache httpclient-4.5.2

**apache logs**
`"[read] I/O error: Read timed out"`

**Java logs**
`Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

**Resttamplate config**

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
        return restTemplate;
    }

@Bean
    public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient());
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }

@Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(180000)
            .setConnectTimeout(180000)
            .setSocketTimeout(180000).build();

        return HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager())
           // .setKeepAliveStrategy(connectionKeepAliveStrategy())
            .build();
    }

@Bean
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(50);
        return poolingConnectionManager;
    }
```

If we add set connectionKeepAliveStrategy in HttpClients.custom() as mentioned below, we won't get any such exception.

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy connectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        return new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
            @Override
            public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
                    (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                    String param = he.getName();
                    String value = he.getValue();

                    if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                    }
                }
                return 20000;
            }
        };
    }
```

Not sure why such exceptions gone with connectionKeepAliveStrategy. What is the role of it in this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the  initialSize for the connection pool

Comment: Try to use HttpClient-4.5.1 as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514825/apache-httpclient-4-5-connection-resets) and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: @jumping_monkey we are getting same issue with version 4.5.7 as well, is it not fixed in this version as well?

Comment: @CodeRider max total is 50, not sure what do you mean by initialSize.

Comment: @jumping_monkey I just tried with 4.5.1, still not fixed.

Comment: Can you provide the logs?

Comment: Do you have a router, firewall or proxy between client and server, which drops idle TCP connections after less than 10 minutes? That would explain the problem.

Comment: @CodeRider Java logs: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Apache logs: [read] I/O error: Read timed out

Comment: @jarnbjo we get these exceptions exactly the same number as setDefaultMaxPerRoute if we run >= value [setDefaultMaxPerRoute] threads concurrently.

Comment: @jarnbjo we don't have firewall in our network. if we talk about proxy, we sometimes get these exception when we call url after 5 minutes interval as well. but most of the time we get it when there if interval of min 10 minutes.

Comment: @AnkurLathiya, thank you for posting this. I have a similar problem and setting the keep-alive fixed my problem. your question/post basically became my answer :D!

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul Please, can you post the exact configuration which you added? Was it a custom keep alive strategy? It seems that the responses we get have "Connection: keep-alive" header but no separate "Keep-Alive" header which makes me suspect that pool connections are being kept for reuse indefinitely (or a big time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [these](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e373) two important points in:
*Section **2.6 - Connection keep alive strategy**:*

1. `Keep-Alive` header in the response

> If the Keep-Alive header is not present in the response, HttpClient
> assumes the connection can be kept alive indefinitely.

***I am guessing there is one `Keep-Alive` header in your api response with a value of 600 seconds.***

2. Custom `keep-alive` strategy:

> However, many HTTP servers in general use are configured to drop
> persistent connections after a certain period of inactivity in order
> to conserve system resources, quite often without informing the
> client. In case the default strategy turns out to be too optimistic,
> one may want to provide a custom keep-alive strategy.